# How to patch with a .diff file?

Tags: diff, patch

I found this patch on source forge ([cocoa.diff](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3107644&group_id=149835&atid=775955)), and it implies that I can patch using the cocoa.diff file. However, I can't seem to figure out how to use the .diff file.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I tried "patch p1 < cocoa.diff" and the output was "patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input." Does this mean that the .diff file is corrupt or incorrect? Also, I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531693/patch-only-garbage-was-found-in-the-patch-input/11744269#11744269

Answer (score 6):

the file cocoa.diff seems OK, however the link failed the first time I tried and returned some error HTML which indeed looks like garbage to `patch`. Your command seems nearly OK (lacks a dash: `patch -p1 < cocoa.diff` seems better).