# How to apply a .diff file

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch

I got a .diff type file , seems like blew:

```
diff --git a/res/User.lua b/res/User.lua
index db8c2cc..4d2af0f 100644
--- a/res/User.lua
+++ b/res/User.lua
@@ -5,6 +5,7 @@ resetPassword = {}
+UserInfo = {}
```

Should i manually modify my local User.lua , or can i apply a diff file as like apply a patch file ? (or should convert a .diff file to .patch file, how to?)

would be thankful for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744269/805284

Answer (score 8):

> should convert a `.diff` file to `.patch` file, how to?

No, the extension isn't important. The content is.

You can try, and if doesn't work, fallback [on this comment](https://drupal.org/comment/6945422#comment-6945422) by [Евгений Чорба (Evgeny Solis)](https://twitter.com/evgeny_solis):

> For those who has no patch command and **[`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)** does nothing. The solution is:
>   Let's modify the patch file!
>
> From

```
diff --git a/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc b/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
index b9a978a..ef33ca3 100644
--- a/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
+++ b/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
```

> To:

```
diff --git ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
index 1c35bf8..587fa67 100755
--- ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
+++ ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc
```

> Apply patch from project root using
>
> git apply -p0 PATCHFILE.patch
>
> Verbose:
>   You should replace '`a/`' and '`b/`' from patchfile with '`<projectname>/`' (In my example it is '`ubercart`')
>
> After applying patch you may see warning like

```
warning: ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.admin.inc has type 100755, expected 100644
```

> It's OK, don't worry.
>
> NOTE! If patch contains diffs for a several files you should replace ALL occurrences of '`a/<anypath>`' and '`b/<anypath>`'

---

Note: the [OP chengpei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731438/chengpei) has [seen the other error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274840/how-to-apply-a-diff-file/21276490?noredirect=1#comment32065598_21276490) when using `git apply`:

```
  got a error: fatal: corrupt patch at line 7
```

It is documented in "[“`fatal: corrupt patch at line XX`” when staging single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548088/6309)"

> having newlines at the end of the file fixes it, and removing them causes it.

---

[Magnus Bäck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414355/magnus-back) recommends [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274840/how-to-apply-a-diff-file/21276490?noredirect=1#comment32074258_21276490):

> Instead of editing the patch file to remove directory prefixes `a/` and `b/`, run **`patch -p1`** to have the first directory component stripped automatically.

[tremby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496046/tremby) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274840/how-to-apply-a-diff-file/21276490#comment55259043_21276490):

> To produce a diff from git without the `a/` and `b/` prefixes you can use `--no-prefix` as an option to `git diff`

Comment: thanks, have tried git apply -p0 PATCHFILE.patch (Acturaly, i tried before,), Unfortunately, got a error:  fatal: corrupt patch at line 7...

Comment: @chengpei did you replace the `a/` and `b/` as mentioned in the answer? and did you apply it from the root folder of your repo?

Comment: i have fixed the " got a error: fatal: corrupt patch at line 7" issue,here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12548088/1731438

Comment: @chengpei Great! I have included your conclusion, as well as a link to the other answer, in my answer for more visibility.

Comment: Instead of editing the patch file to remove directory prefixes a/ and b/, run `patch -p1` to have the first directory component stripped automatically.

Comment: @MagnusBäck good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: To produce a diff from git without the `a/` and `b/` prefixes you can use `--no-prefix` as an option to `git diff`.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Where and when do you use `patch -p1`? What would the full command look like?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts To apply a patch created with `git diff` instead of `git diff --no-prefix`: see https://gist.github.com/zeuxisoo/980174 and https://medium.com/odds-team/create-a-patch-file-from-git-diff-c746be60d1e